# Extracting text of <p></p> with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the news article from [this](http://www.aninews.in/newsdetail-Nw/MzI4NDIy/ios-developer-hints-possibility-of-4k-apple-tv.html) link. My code is :

```
def get_news_details(news_url):
    source = requests.get(news_url)
    plain_text = source.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    content = soup.findAll('div', {'class' : 'big-img-box'})
    print(content[0].findAll('p'))
```

The result shows :

```
[<p></p>, <p></p>, <p></p>, <p></p>, <p></p>, <p></p>]
```

And the value of `content` is :

```
<div class="big-img-box">
<div class="left-imgs">
<figure>
<img alt="iOS developer hints possibility of 4K Apple TV" class="img-responsive" src="http://www.aninews.in/contentimages/detail/appletv.jpg"/>
<figcaption><span class="heading-inner-span"></span></figcaption>
</figure>
<div class="mb10"></div>
</div>
<p></p>      New York [USA], August 6 <a class="highlights" href="http://aninews.in/" target="_blank">(ANI)</a>: The latest designs from Apple's HomePod firmware revealed that the tech giant is hinting the launch of a <span class="highlights"><a href="http://aninews.in/keysearch/keyword-search/4k-apple-tv.html"> 4K Apple TV</a></span> with high dynamic range (HDR)  support for both <span class="highlights"><a href="http://aninews.in/keysearch/keyword-search/hdr10.html"> HDR10  </a></span> and <span class="highlights"><a href="http://aninews.in/keysearch/keyword-search/dolby-vision.html"> Dolby Vision</a></span>.<p></p>      While the current range of Apple's TV set-top box is incompatible to 4K technology, <span class="highlights"><a href="http://aninews.in/keysearch/keyword-search/ios.html">iOS</a></span> developer <span class="highlights"><a href="http://aninews.in/keysearch/keyword-search/guilherme-rambo.html"> Guilherme Rambo</a></span> revealed that the company is hinting an adoption of the ultra high-definition format, reports <span class="highlights"><a href="http://aninews.in/keysearch/keyword-search/the-verge.html">The Verge</a></span>.<p></p>      Reports of the new range of Apple TV have surfaced time and again over the past few months, starting February this year.<p></p>      It is said that implementing the HDR and 4K content will prove to b beneficial for the company, rather than a simpler resolution, since popular online movie and television platforms like <span class="highlights"><a href="http://aninews.in/keysearch/keyword-search/netflix.html"> Netflix</a></span> and <span class="highlights"><a href="http://aninews.in/keysearch/keyword-search/amazon.html"> Amazon</a></span> support the two high-definition formats.<p></p>      Last month, iTunes started listing movies as supporting 4K and <span class="highlights"><a href="http://aninews.in/keysearch/keyword-search/hdr.html"> HDR</a></span> in users' purchase histories, thus providing more thrust to the speculations of the 4K <span class="highlights"><a href="http://aninews.in/keysearch/keyword-search/apple.html"> Apple</a></span> TV. <a class="highlights" href="http://aninews.in/" target="_blank">(ANI)</a><p></p>
</div>
```

I can get a somewhat clumsy version of the article by `content[0].text` but I cannot format it.

While inspecting the webpage in chrome, the article seems to be written inside `<p>article_text</p>` tags. Whereas in `content`, it appears as `<p></p>article_text` tags. If the former version is present in `soup`, I can get my desired output. What should be done ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by formatting. You can make it 'tidier' in fairly simple ways.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('http://www.aninews.in/newsdetail-Nw/MzI4NDIy/ios-developer-hints-possibility-of-4k-apple-tv.html').content
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> big_img_box = soup.select('.big-img-box')
```

Get all the text and strip away white space.

```
>>> big_img_box[0].text.strip()
"New York [USA], August 6 (ANI): The latest designs from Apple's HomePod firmware revealed that the tech giant is hinting the launch of a  4K Apple TV with high dynamic range (HDR)  support for both  HDR10   and  Dolby Vision.      While the current range of Apple's TV set-top box is incompatible to 4K technology, iOS developer  Guilherme Rambo revealed that the company is hinting an adoption of the ultra high-definition format, reports The Verge.      Reports of the new range of Apple TV have surfaced time and again over the past few months, starting February this year.      It is said that implementing the HDR and 4K content will prove to b beneficial for the company, rather than a simpler resolution, since popular online movie and television platforms like  Netflix and  Amazon support the two high-definition formats.      Last month, iTunes started listing movies as supporting 4K and  HDR in users' purchase histories, thus providing more thrust to the speculations of the 4K  Apple TV. (ANI)"
```

Go beyond this and remove longer strings of interior white space.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', big_img_box[0].text.strip())
"New York [USA], August 6 (ANI): The latest designs from Apple's HomePod firmware revealed that the tech giant is hinting the launch of a 4K Apple TV with high dynamic range (HDR) support for both HDR10 and Dolby Vision. While the current range of Apple's TV set-top box is incompatible to 4K technology, iOS developer Guilherme Rambo revealed that the company is hinting an adoption of the ultra high-definition format, reports The Verge. Reports of the new range of Apple TV have surfaced time and again over the past few months, starting February this year. It is said that implementing the HDR and 4K content will prove to b beneficial for the company, rather than a simpler resolution, since popular online movie and television platforms like Netflix and Amazon support the two high-definition formats. Last month, iTunes started listing movies as supporting 4K and HDR in users' purchase histories, thus providing more thrust to the speculations of the 4K Apple TV. (ANI)"
```

Comment: This works for me (I actually meant "tidier", thanks for clarifying). But I want to know why there is a difference between Chrome's Inspection of the page (`<p>text</p>`) and BeautifulSoup's version (`<p></p>text`) ?

Comment: I don't know for sure. However, I would say that , when either browser software or BeautifulSoup encounters a page that isn't coded to meet its standards it must do something to that code in order to display it. It's possible that Chrome's designers go in one direction when faced with a problem and BeautifulSoup's another one. The results in this case are a little different.

Comment: @BillBell Hey Bill I just wanted to show you my gratitude for showing such good support to this StackOverflow tag and generally your support to the community, you're a nice guy. Wish you all the best, I just wanted you to know how we all appreciate your help.

Comment: @ElvirMuslic: Thanks very much! It really is my pleasure.